# Postfix Connection refused (port 25)

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to send email through a Postfix server. From the command line, if I enter:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "subject line" me@example.com`
```

Then the error I see in log/mail.info is:

```
postfix/smtp[23093]: connect to mail.mydomain.com[my.ip.add.here]: Connection refused (port 25)
```

If I enter netstat -an |more, I see:

```
...
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...
```

No `0.0.0.0:25` if that makes a difference?

**Edit**

If I run `netstat -plntu`, then I see `3587/master` as the pid/program name for 127.0.0.1:25. I see no postfix listed for pid/program name. Could it be that the mail server isn't running. I was told that it was.

```
...
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3587/master
...
```

**Edit**

Confirmed Postfix is running by typing `postfix start`

**Edit**

Tried this on the server if it helps:

```
telnet mail.mydomain.com 25
Trying 202.192.77.135...
telnet: connect to address 202.192.77.135: Connection refused
```

I know this problem has been solved many times, but I'm a simple web developer and I might need a little more guidance. Thank you.

Comment: So you are trying to send a mail to the local server? In that case just use `me@localhost`.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, I'm trying to send mail to the outside world. Apparently the mail server was working with the php web app at one point, but then mysteriously stopped working one day due to connection refused on port 25.

Comment: Do you know which mail server is running on `example.com`? Maybe `postfix`?

Comment: can you open a socket outbound on port 25?
`nc vegas.jacobdevans.com 25 -v`

Comment: -bash: nc: command not found

Comment: Postfix is running. I verified by running `postfix start`

Comment: is that server meant for sending only?

Comment: I don't know. Can I find out by running a command?

Comment: @RickJolly go to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and have a look there, option `inet_interfaces`

Comment: inet_interfaces = localhost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mail log shows that you CAN connect to your postfix server (on localhost). The postfix cannot connect to the external smtp server (mail.mydomain.com), and you can't connect with telnet either.

Perhaps you have a firewall (at your ISP) that blocks the outgoing smtp. This is common to block spam. For workaround you can use other mail server (gmail?) for relaying your e-mails, and connect to it on secure smtp (port 465 / 587) and authentication.

This is a great howto for this: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/configure-postfix-to-use-gmail-as-a-mail-relay/

Comment: Thanks @DBLaci. I'll look into it and get back to you. Just out for a few hours.

Comment: Thanks so much. The ISP was blocking port 25. I could send using my gmail creds on port 587.